# find number of rows in a 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

[How to find number of rows in dynamic 2D char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481251/how-to-find-number-of-rows-in-dynamic-2d-char-array-in-c)

Nothing from there.

tried with following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int k = 97;
void foo(char **a)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; a[i] != NULL; ++i)
      printf("i = %d\n", i);
}

void strcpyo(char* a, char*b){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++){
        a[i]=b[i];
    }
    a[i]='\0';
}

void strcpym(char* a, char*b){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++);
    memcpy(a,b,i+1);

}
void freee(char** ptr){
int i;
        for(i = 0;i < k; ++i)
        {
            free(ptr[i] );
        }
    free(ptr);

}

void alloc(char ***p)
{
    *p = (char **)malloc(k * sizeof(char *));

    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
       // for(i = 0;i < j; ++i)
        {
            (*p)[j] = (char *)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((*p)[j],"paicharan");
        }
        //printf("j = %d ", j);
        //foo(p);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **p;
    alloc(&p);
#if 0
    char **p = (char **)malloc(k * sizeof(char *));
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        for(i = 0;i < j; ++i)
        {
            p[i] = (char *)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(p[i],"paicharan");
        }
        printf("j = %d ", j);
        foo(p);
    }
#endif
    foo(p);
    freee(p);
    return 0;
}
```

The code in `#if 0` `#endif` works perfectly, but if I do create arrays in function `alloc(char**)` it's giving the wrong answer for odd number of rows in array. Can anybody explain why?

ie. for `k= odd number` it gives out wrong answer but for `even number` its correct.

Comment: Oops, [a three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)!

Comment: just wanted to show you both methods so used 3 star :p

Comment: Your already start with a problem of vocabulary: the things you handle  are *not* 2D arrays but pointers to pointers. If you have a chance to avoid such a maintenance nightmare, just use real 2D arrays. The language has them they are clean and much easier to use.

Comment: ya ya.. can i say its a dynamic 2D array ? anyway, my question was something different than what u thinking :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code depends on [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/183120) to work correctly i.e. it'll work only by chance. This has got nothing to do with even or odd count of elements.

In the `void alloc(char ***p)` function you allocate memory for `k` pointer to pointer to char: `char**`. Then you fill all of the `k` pointers with new valid `char*` pointers i.e. none of them are NULL. Later in `void foo(char **a)` you do `for(i=0; a[i] != NULL; ++i)`; since `a[k - 1]` was non-null, it'll iterate over them correctly. BUT after that **`a[k]` may or may not be NULL**, you never know what is in there. Also accessing what is beyond the array you allocated is undefined behaviour (due to out of bounds access).

Making `k + 1` elements and setting the k<sup>th</sup>  element to NULL makes this work; make sure you free all of `k + 1` elements and not leak the last [sentinal element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Since you told that the code wraped inside the macro works fine, I've ignored that; don't know if there's UB there too. If you're doing this exercise to learn, it's fine. If you are planning to do some other project, try to reuse some existing C library which already gives these facilities.